# Trouble loading data from txt file into MySQL with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am having a hard time loading my data to MySQL from a text file. I have been attempting to choose the correct delimiters but my file contains column names with each value.

The data is structured like this

```
{"id":"15","name":"greg","age":"32"}
{"id":"16","name":"jim","age":"42"}
```

the sql statement I am working on looks something like this currently

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/xxx.txt' INTO TABLE t1 FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(id, name, age);
```

results are being stored like this

```
{"id":"16", "name","greg"}
```

I need to do away with the column name and store the value.

any tips?

Comment: Load data infile is for loading data from csv files. Your file seems to be a list of json entities that can't be handled by load data. You probably need to develop a script in an external programming language that parses this file and can import its contents into mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Writing a script as suggested by @Shadow will be easier to wrap around but you can check the section on json on this page [how to import json-text-xml and csv data into mysql](https://developpaper.com/how-to-import-json-text-xml-csv-data-files-into-mysql/)
or
[Import JSON to MySQL made easy with the MySQL Shell](https://mysqlserverteam.com/import-json-to-mysql-made-easy-with-the-mysql-shell/) if you are using MySQL Shell 8.0.13 (GA)